# Is it possible in azure to have policy to enforce a pricing tier?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, policy

I would like to have a policy to enforce a specific pricing tier when any user create the sql database resource.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The General Purpose service tier is a default service tier in Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance that is designed for most of generic workloads.

We can not change the default price tier for now.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-general-purpose#when-to-choose-this-service-tier

Comment: I would like to set a policy to enforce the basic tier. As you said, it is impossible  is not it?

Comment: Hi@LeandroDuarte, Per my experience, that's impossible for now.

Comment: Thank you Leon! Nice to meet you!